# Why doesn't multiprocessing pool map speed up compared to serial map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I have this very simple python code that I want to speed up by parallelizing it. However no matter what I seem to do, `multiprocessing.Pool.map` doesn't gain anything over the standard map.

I've read other threads where people use this with very small functions that don't parallelize well and lead to excessive overhead but I would think that shouldn't be the case here.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here's the example

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy, time

def AddNoise(sample):
    #time.sleep(0.001)
    return sample + numpy.random.randint(0,9,sample.shape)
    #return sample + numpy.ones(sample.shape)

n=100
m=10000
start = time.time()
A = list([ numpy.random.randint(0,9,(n,n)) for i in range(m) ])
print("creating %d numpy arrays of %d x %d took %.2f seconds"%(m,n,n,time.time()-start))

for i in range(3):
    start = time.time()
    A = list(map(AddNoise, A))
    print("adding numpy arrays took %.2f seconds"%(time.time()-start))

for i in range(3):
    import multiprocessing
    start = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        A = list(pool.map(AddNoise, A, chunksize=100))
    print("adding numpy arrays with multiprocessing Pool took %.2f seconds"%(time.time()-start))

for i in range(3):
    import concurrent.futures
    start = time.time()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        A = list(executor.map(AddNoise, A))
    print("adding numpy arrays with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor took %.2f seconds"%(time.time()-start))
```

Which results in the following output on my 4-core/8-thread laptop, which is idle otherwise

```
$ python test-pool.py 
creating 10000 numpy arrays of 100 x 100 took 1.54 seconds
adding numpy arrays took 1.65 seconds
adding numpy arrays took 1.51 seconds
adding numpy arrays took 1.51 seconds
adding numpy arrays with multiprocessing Pool took 1.99 seconds
adding numpy arrays with multiprocessing Pool took 1.98 seconds
adding numpy arrays with multiprocessing Pool took 1.94 seconds
adding numpy arrays with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor took 3.32 seconds
adding numpy arrays with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor took 3.17 seconds
adding numpy arrays with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor took 3.25 seconds
```

Comment: If it can be done in numpy then it's probably sidestepping the GIL anyway, which is the primary reason for using `multiprocessing`.

Comment: But also the standard `map` call doesn't use more 100% cpu.

Comment: Standard map can never use more than 1 core because of the GIL

Comment: @roganjosh to answer your previous comment: on my notebook the time to create a pool of two processes is around 4.5ms.

Comment: @RobertoTrani interesting, how did you test it? `timeit` has spammed my system with processes so I don't doubt that slowed things down, but did you do it in a loop and close each pool?

Comment: @roganjosh, after a first attempt with `%timeit`, with your same result :D, I used `%time` a couple of times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the result transfer. Consider that with multiprocessing the arrays you create inside the child processes need to be transferred back to the main process.. and this is an overhead.

I checked this modifying the AddNoise function in this way, which preserve the computation time, but discard the transfer time:

```
def AddNoise(sample):
   sample + numpy.random.randint(0,9,sample.shape)
   return None
```

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. So then if I understand correctly I can never benefit from a multiprocessing Pool .. unless I can make the memory shared somehow.

Comment: That's the trick. You can benefit from multiprocessing only if the effort to compute something is big compared to the communication overhead. If you use read-only objects this is free to use on linux machines, because of the copy-on-write behaviour. However, for write or shared objects this is tricky, and there isn't a standard answer if you can or cannot.

Comment: @jaap but if this is actually representative of the task you're trying to complete, you should just do it in numpy (properly, with vectorized calculations) with no multiprocessing and it'll be faster still, regardless of problem size.

Comment: @roganjosh is right. When I really need to parallelize computations like this I use cython code with nogil in conjunction with a thread pool. But it requires a lot more effort...

Comment: Ok, thanks yes this solves it then. This actually representative so I'll try to rewrite in a more native way.

Comment: You answer only addresses half the problem. Just changing the return value to `None` in `AddNoise()` only gets rid of about half of the transferring that's going on. There's also the overhead of passing the argument `A` _to_ the function via the `map(AddNoise, A)` calls. `A` is huge so transferring it between processes in _either_ direction increases the overhead significantly.

Comment: Or, set the chunksize to 1 and the time is cut in half.   Still not faster than the serial code, but that is probably communication overhead, as described above.