# Multiprocessing slower than serial processing in Windows (but not in Linux)

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize a `for loop` to speed-up my code, since the loop processing operations are all independent. Following online tutorials, it seems the standard `multiprocessing` library in Python is a good start, and I've got this working for basic examples.

However, for my actual use case, I find that parallel processing (using a dual core machine) is actually a little (<5%) slower, when run on Windows. Running the same code on Linux, however, results in a parallel processing speed-up of ~25%, compared to serial execution.

From the docs, I believe this may relate to Window's lack of fork() function, which means the process needs to be initialised fresh each time. However, I don't fully understand this and wonder if anyone can confirm this please?

Particularly,

--> Does this mean that all code in the calling python file gets run for each parallel process on Windows, even initialising classes and importing packages?

--> If so, can this be avoided by somehow passing a copy (e.g. using deepcopy) of the class into the new processes?

--> Are there any tips / other strategies for efficient parallelisation of code design for both unix and windows.

My exact code is long and uses many files, so I have created a pseucode-style example structure which hopefully shows the issue.

```
# Imports
from my_package import MyClass
imports many other packages / functions

# Initialization (instantiate class and call slow functions that get it ready for processing)
my_class = Class()
my_class.set_up(input1=1, input2=2)

# Define main processing function to be used in loop
def calculation(_input_data):
    # Perform some functions on _input_data
    ......
    # Call method of instantiate class to act on data
    return my_class.class_func(_input_data)

input_data = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
output_data = np.zeros_like(input_data)

# For Loop (SERIAL implementation)
for i, x in enumerate(input_data):
    output_data[i] = calculation(x)

# PARALLEL implementation (this doesn't work well!)
with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    results = pool.map_async(calculation, input_data)
    results.wait()
output_data = results.get()
```

EDIT: I do not believe the question is a duplicate of the one suggested, since this relates to a difference in Windows and Linunx, which is not mentioned at all in the suggested duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't multiprocessing pool map speed up compared to serial map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489753/why-doesnt-multiprocessing-pool-map-speed-up-compared-to-serial-map)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NT Operating Systems lack the UNIX `fork` primitive. When a new process is created, it starts as a blank process. It's responsibility of the parent to instruct the new process on how to bootstrap.

Python `multiprocessing` APIs abstracts the process creation trying to give the same feeling for the `fork`, `forkserver` and `spawn` start methods.

When you use the `spawn` starting method, this is what happens under the hood.

1. A blank process is created
2. The blank process starts a brand new Python interpreter
3. The Python interpreter is given the MFA (Module Function Arguments) you specified via the `Process` class initializer
4. The Python interpreter loads the given module resolving all the imports
5. The `target` function is looked up within the module and called with the given `args` and `kwargs`

The above flow brings few implications.

As you noticed yourself, it is a much more taxing operation compared to `fork`. That's why you notice such a difference in performance.

As the module gets imported from scratch in the child process, all import side effects are executed anew. This means that constants, [global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961490/multiprocessing-event-not-working/49975240#49975240), [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936735/a-timeout-decorator-class-with-multiprocessing-gives-a-pickling-error/49940260#49940260) and first level instructions will be executed again.

On the other side, initializations made during the parent process execution will not be propagated to the child. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782749/processpoolexecutor-logging-fails-to-log-inside-function-on-windows-but-not-on-u/49791106#49791106) example.

This is why in the `multiprocessing` documentation they added a specific paragraph for Windows in the [Programming Guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods). I highly recommend to read the Programming Guidelines as they already include all the required information to write portable multi-processing code.